Kubernetes Persistent Volume not shared when uploading a file with Django and Nginx
I created 2 persistant volumes, one for static files and other for media files.
The static files one works just fine, nginx serves the data.
For media volume, nginx does not see the uploaded file and the volume content does not update.
The nginx conf is fine. The location works but volume does not contain the uploaded file.
This is my media pv and pvc:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mediafiles-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/usr/src/app/backend/media"

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mediafiles-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: mediafiles-pv

This is my deployment for backend (django):
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: staticfiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: staticfiles-pvc
        - name: mediafiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mediafiles-pvc
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: loopedupl/backend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/backend/static"
            - name: mediafiles
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/backend/media"

and for nginx:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: staticfiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: staticfiles-pvc
        - name: mediafiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mediafiles-pvc
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: loopedupl/nginx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/backend/static"
            - name: mediafiles
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/backend/media"

When accessing django pod, I can see the uploaded file in this directory. When accessing nginx pod the data is not there. The media folder is empty.
It seems fine when using locally on docker-compose.
Do not really see the difference between media and static volume.

The hostPath: volume type refers to a directory on whichever node the Pod happens to be running on.  It's not a reliable way to share files, assuming you have multiple nodes (and you almost always do if you've gone to the trouble of using Kubernetes).  Can you delete the manual PersistentVolume object and let the cluster provision one for you?  Or can you have the backend Pod serve its own assets and media, and avoid the file-sharing problem altogether?
